# IAuthorizationFilter's OnAuthorization method not being called

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've written a custom authorization filter for use with the AngularJS XSRF approach however the filter isn't being called.

The strange thing is that I copied it from another project and it seems to work fine there.

Here's the attrubute/filter code.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class ValidateAngularAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            string token = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"];
            object sessionToken = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["XSRF-TOKEN"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) || sessionToken == null || sessionToken.ToString() != token)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here it is adorning an action in a WebAPI controller.

```
[Authorize]
public class WorksOrdersController : ApiController
{        
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAngularAntiForgeryToken]
    public void EmailJob(int id, EmailModel model)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Do I have to add something to the Web.config to get it to work? I can't see anything dramatically different in the web.config of the project that's actually working.

Comment: An Authorization Attribute needs to inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute`, not from its inherited classes, in my experience. Also, `OnAuthorize` is the wrong function to override, you need to override `AuthorizeCore`, which takes an HttpContextBase as its argument.

Comment: I think thats one alternative but I can't access the session from the AuthorizeAttribute though. That doesn't explain why the same code works in my other solution either.

Comment: A missing important detail, it's on an action in an ApiController.

Comment: In non-core MVC, I inherited from System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was that there are two `IAuthorizationFilter` interfaces in ASP.NET now.

One in `System.Web.Mvc` for use with "normal" view controllers and one in `System.Web.Http.Filters` for use with WebAPI.

I had the wrong `using` statement in the version that didn't work.

Comment: This is a key issue. Most examples don't show the Using statements used, so this can be confusing and frustrating. I also inherited my custom attribute from System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.

Answer (score 2):

There're two things might be causing this behavior.

**1st** - You putted an `AuthorizeAttribute` in your controller. When you have a Authorize in a controller(class) and in an action(method), the both will be used to authorization. First it is called the controller's authorization attribute. If this allow access then is called the action's authorization attribute.

By default `AuthorizeAttribute` use `Membership` if you not set `Membership` this attribute will denied your acess and the `ValidateAngularAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` will not be called.

Try comment the line `[Authorize]`, before controller, and run a test see if your attribute is called now.

**2nd** - Try convert your attribute to something like @siva. k said. like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidateAngularAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var token = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"];
        var sessionToken = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["XSRF-TOKEN"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) || sessionToken == null || sessionToken.ToString() != token)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused for me because I forgot to call the register filters method in Application_Start... A silly problem, but if it saves someone a day of troubleshooting, its worth it.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
}
```